# Can we have multiple parallel transactions for single database connection?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

Can we obtain multiple **transactions** from **Single Database Connection**?

> In **Hibernate** generally we have only Single instance of **SessionFactory** which internally gets the DB Connection from **Connection Pool**. When we get new **Session** from **SessionFactory** does it internally fetches new connection pool or it shares the **Database connection** across multiple **Session**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate is an ORM, it is a layer between a SQL database and your POJOs.

A connection pool provides a way to store and reuse `java.sql.Connection` instances for speed and robustness.

A hibernate `Session` is a wrapper around a `Connection` in order to allow you to save your POJOs without directly writing the SQL.

So a hibernate `Session` is a wrapper around a `Connection`. `Connections` are held in a connection pool.

When you call `SessionFactory.openSession` hibernate first takes a `Connection` from the supplied connection pool. It then creates a `Session` around that `Connection` and returns it.

When using Hibernate with a connection pool, whenever a Session needs a JDBC Connection, it allocates it from the pool.

When the session is done, it's behavior depends upon `ConnectionReleaseMode`. For Hibernate 3.1, the default `ConnectionReleaseMode` is `AFTER_TRANSACTION` (was ON_CLOSE), meaning that a `Session` releases Connection back to pool at the `transaction` end (commit or rollback).

Answer (score 0):

SessionFactory does not gets the DB connection. SessionFactory is threadsafe, loads hibernate.cfg.xml file and threads can access it concurrently and request for sessions and  immutable cache of compiled mappings for a single database. When the SessionFactory is build, all the Entity classes will be mapped.

You can get any number of Session instances from the SessionFactory. Sessions are not threadsafe, ie., you cannot share Sessions between threads. A session obtains the database connection lazily. 
beginTransaction() will cause the load of the connection for the given Session only if there is a need, ie., only if the transaction is started.